# Azure App Service ASP.NET Web API OWIN OAuth path not found

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, owin

I am hosting an ASP.NET Web API on Azure App Service. The Web API has OWIN OAuth authentication with an endpoint `api/token`. The api runs fine in an IIS environment. For some reason when hosted on Azure App Service the token endpoint isn't working and results in the following error: `the controller for path 'api/token' was not found or does not implement icontroller`.

The owin startup class is called. The startup class looks as followed:

```
 OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(authenticationElement.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan),
            Provider = provider,
            RefreshTokenProvider = new GrcApiRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AllowInsecureHttp = authenticationElement.AllowInsecureHttp
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

        //Token Consumption
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use `https` instead of `http`. Altough the owin middleware was set to allow insecure.